# MongoDB - Capturing Dropped Objects From A Capped Collection

Tags: collections, mongodb

Quoting from the [MongoDB docs on Capped Collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections):

> Once the space is fully utilized,
>   newly added objects will replace the
>   oldest objects in the collection.

Is there any way to capture a capped collection's "dropped" objects before they are overwritten ? What I am interested in doing is implementing a series of rollup collections. eg.

```
Hourly --> Daily --> Weekly --> Monthly  etc.
```

so when an object is dropped from the Hourly collections, I want to capture it and aggregate it up to the Daily collection.

Thanks in advance.

//Nicholas

Comment: Even if the feature is not supported, you can always file a JIRA at https://jira.mongodb.org or better yet discuss your use case with the developers directly at http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user - they are pretty fast in replying. If you make a strong case for your use case it may be implemented sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the MongoDB developers, you can't do this:

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/aec8d0c85f58d89e/d6701df083eb4679?fwc=1

> What I am interested in doing is implementing a series of rollup collections.

As alex said, one way to solve this is to use MapReduce. Another way is to have a different collection e.g. per day, for example logs20110414 and have your application manage read/writes to the appropriate collection.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to implement that functionality in code rather than in MongoDB.

I don't think Capped Collections are the right solution for your use-case.

You *could* insert into a capped collection, and at the same time insert into a "normal" collection, and aggregate them into hourly / daily, weekly, monthly etc... using map reduce.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Too bad it is not supported. Capped Collections have 2 features I really need which are the circular storage and the tailable cursors.